# Monitoring Elastic Search possible responses

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We are using RestHighLevelClient class to communicate with the Elastic Search.
When I am trying to index some json into the ES, I get some response back.

The failed responses can be divided into 2 groups:

1. Retryable failures - caused by some temporary problems (the elastic server is too busy and Etc) and can be succeed after an immidiate retry.
2. Total Failure - caused by some harder problems (connections lost and Etc) and some mechanism will be activated.

When I get the responses, I need to match each one to the correct type.
To do that, I need some list of all possible responses from the Elastic Search which I can't find!
I searched everywhere..

Does someone had the same issue?